# Alternar variável dentro do While

Tags: php, lógica

O meu sistema faz o controle de viagens de veículos. Quando o cliente insere uma determinada viagem para uma linha, esta linha tem dois veículos associados a ela. Então ele pega o período, por exemplo de `04/02/2019` a `08/02/2019`, pega estes dois veículos e insere as viagens na tabela de viagens, através do `while`. Só que eu preciso alternar os veículos, cada dia ele vai inserir um veículo diferente. Queria tentar fazer isso sem precisar ficar consultando a tabela de viagens a cada `insert` dentro do `while`.

```
public function store_teste(Request $request)
{
    $inicio = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $request->input('inicio'))));
    $fim = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $request->input('fim'))));
    $veiculo1 = $request->input('veiculo1');
    $veiculo2 = $request->input('veiculo2');

    while (strtotime($inicio) <= strtotime($dtfim2)) {           

        //ROTINA DO INSERT            
        //Na primeira passagem pelo while vai inserir o veículo1
        //Na segunda passagem pelo while vai inserir o veículo2
        //Na terceira pasagem pelo while vai inserir o veículo1
        //Na quarta pasagem pelo while vai inserir o veículo2

    $inicio = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($inicio))); 
    }


}
```

Não tem dia do mês ou semana fixos, o primeiro registro inserido vai o veículo 1, no segundo vai o 2. E aí vai alternando dependendo da quantidade de dias.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta lógica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os exemplos aqui estão no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/LdTMfV)**.

Tem várias maneiras. Veja algumas:

### Alternando com subtração

```
$alterna = 1;
while ( ... ) {           
   $alterna = 1 - $alterna; // Ou vai ser 1-0, ou 1-1 sempre
   if ($alterna) {
      // var1
   } else {
      // var2
   }
```

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```
$alterna = 1;
while ( ... ) {           
   $alterna = 1 - $alterna; // se for true vira false, se for false vira true
   $veiculo1 = $request->input($alterna?'veiculo1':'veiculo2');
}
```

### Alternando com negação lógica

```
$alterna = true;
while ( ... ) {           
   $alterna = !$alterna;
   $veiculo1 = $request->input($alterna?'veiculo1':'veiculo2');
}
```

Esta linha aqui:

```
$alterna = !$alterna;
```

equivale a outras construções (umas meio malucas) que você encontra na web:

```
$alterna = ($alterna == false);
$alterna = $alterna ? false : true; // essas são de doer, mas já vi piores
```

### Alternando com inversão de bits

```
$alterna = 0;
while ( ... ) {           
   $alterna = ~$alterna;
   $veiculo1 = $request->input($alterna?'veiculo1':'veiculo2');
}
```

Ou ainda, invertendo o primeiro bit:

```
$alterna = 0;
while ( ... ) {           
   $alterna ^= 1;
   $veiculo1 = $request->input($alterna?'veiculo1':'veiculo2');
}
```

Nos exemplos acima estamos criando uma situação em que só temos dois estados possíveis. Tem muitas outras maneiras.

### Alternando com operador de resto

Se fosse em um loop com contador incremental de 1 em 1 (como a maioria dos *loops*):

```
if ($contador % 2) {
   // var1
} else {
   // var2
}
```

no seu caso:

```
$veiculo1 = $request->input($contador%2?'veiculo1':'veiculo2');
```

Isto funciona, pois o operador de resto `%` será sempre zero ou um num contador sequencial (trabalhando com inteiros).